Is 4-velocity a Vector in the Sense of Covariant Derivative along Worldline
The definition of 4-velocity $U^{\mu} \equiv dx^{\mu}(\tau)/d\tau$, however, we've learnt that the covariant derivative for a vector along a curve parametrized by proper time is,
$$\frac{DA^{\mu}}{D\tau}=\frac{dA^{\mu}}{d\tau}+\Gamma^{\mu}_{\lambda\nu}\frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\tau}A^{\lambda}$$
in the sense that the covariant derivative is a vector.
However, if I plug in $x^{\mu}$ into above definition, it is not obvious that $Dx/D\tau$ equals to $U=dx/d\tau$ 4-velocity, and it seems confusing to me that 4-velocity is a vector in this sense?

Perhaps check under what conditions the four velocity definition you quote is valid. If it is along worldlines I suspect maybe it is actually the Lie derivative along a flow, while the covariant derivative is more general and can be along more types of spacetime paths.

Note that the parameter $\tau$ is a scalar field normalized along the direction of $U$:
$$U^a\nabla_a\tau=U^a\frac{\partial\tau}{\partial x^a}=1$$
which implies $U^a=\frac{dx^a}{d\tau}$. Now the directional derivative along $U$ is defined as:
$$\frac{D}{D\tau}=U^a\nabla_a$$
As you can notice, the definition involves covariant derivative, and therefore, such derivative operators can only act on tensors. Position coordinate $x^a$ is not a tensor and its not meaningful to define anything like $Dx/D\tau$. To get away with this, you can think of each coordinate as an independent scalar field so that
$$\frac{Dx^a}{D\tau}=U^b\nabla_b x^a \equiv U^b\partial_b x^a = \frac{dx^a}{d\tau}=U^a$$
This should solve the inconsistency
